# Абсолютное центрирование блока на HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Как разместить элемент с классом `center` по центру экрана?

```html
<body>
    <wrapper>
        <div class="center">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </wrapper>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А я бы не стал через absolute делать, темболее через transform

Comment: @Doofy: зависит от условий, ну и от требуемой поддержки браузерами. Может проект для воскрешения динозавров? :)

Comment: @UModeL так и останемся в прошлом, с лагающими сайтами с анимациями на js. Ведь проекты, которые не обновляются - мёртвые проекты :)

Comment: @Doofy: для меня отправной точкой является связка WinXP+Chrome49 (очень много такого добра ещё). Естественно никаких Opera12 и IE.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант на основе `display: grid;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <wrapper>
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>Test</p>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
  </wrapper>
</body>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Как-то делал разметку с использованием `grid`, а потом браузерные движки что-то обновили и всё съехало, пришлось всё переделывать. С этим методом осторожней :)

Comment: @Doofy: это, да... Такое впечатление, что разрабы совсем не проводят опросы и тестирование, и что есть у них тестовый проект и один единственный чел подгоняет браузер под свои фантазии.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `display: flex;` у родителя и всё что внутри установить по центру по горизонтали `justify-content: center;` и вертикали `align-items: center;`, при том каждый родитель должен иметь ширину и высоту, на которую `wrapper` будет опираться.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

wrapper {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <wrapper>
        <div class='center'>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </wrapper>
</body>
```

Так же можно использовать `position: absolute;` у наследователя, но при этом родитель должен иметь `position: relative;`

Comment: Ну, хоть кто-то объясняет про опорные размеры.